# Recover deleted local repository, got source files with file recovery but not recognizing as Git

Tags: git

I accidentally deleted my local repository. Before that I was working in a branch, I made a commit and switched to master after sometime i accidentally deleted my Android Studio project and made my nightmare started. Unfortunately my remote repository is way too behind.

Very soon enough I recovered deleted local repository folder by data recovery software. It has all project files and also folder named git not .git and git folder has directory named 'hooks', 'info', 'logs', 'refs' and file named COMMIT_EDITMSG, cnfig, description, HEAD, index. Now if I go to this repo directory and give any git command it says 'Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)'. I renamed git folder to .git to see if it work.

I don't know what should I do to recover my git branches. What I want is get my working state back. Please help me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many source files are in your project?

Comment: 30906 files, 887 folders. project was alright as it was in master branch i opened it in my ide.

Comment: How many files did you actually modify since you last synched up with the remote?

Comment: I'm not an expert in git but I know that the folders you mentioned are created when you add the flag `--bare` to a `clone` or `fetch`. You can google for `--bare` and get more info. I'm sorry but I don't know how to revert it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a anothe folder somewhere else in directory.
2. do a `git init`
3. Copy all objects from your original projects to new folder where you initialized new git(including git folder, use a .git folder).
4. Then run `git fsck` in the new repository. ( Verifies the connectivity and validity of the objects in the database)
5. Try `git show` or `git log` to see if you can access branch or commits.

I'm not 100% positive you can recover but let's see.

Comment: Then I guess, you've no choice but to rewrite lost code, sorry my answer didn't help.